# Is it possible to disable the swiping of flutter_swiper for few seconds dynamically?

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter_swiper 1.1.6 in my app to display images. But for some indices i want to disable swiping of swiper for few seconds.

Here is my code:

```
Swiper(
  index: inx,
  itemCount: swiperList.length,
  itemWidth: double.infinity,
  loop: false,
  viewportFraction: 0.85,
  scale: 0.8,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if(index == Indexer.CELL) {
      //disable swiping
    }

    return Container(...);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may disable user interaction with the widgets for few seconds by wrapping the widgets with either AbsorbPointer or IgnorePointer. Please see code below for reference.

```
....
bool absorbing = false;
......

AbsorbPointer(
absorbing : absorbing,
child: Swiper(
  index: inx,
  itemCount: swiperList.length,
  itemWidth: double.infinity,
  loop: false,
  viewportFraction: 0.85,
  scale: 0.8,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if(index == Indexer.CELL) {
      setState(() { absorbing=true; });
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      setState(() { absorbing=false; });
     });
    }

    return Container(...);
  },
),);
```

Comment: I tried this solution but on using setState state of swiper resets, it takes swiper back to 0th index. Is it suppose to behave like this?

Comment: On using setState all user interaction with Swiper stops for 5 seconds. There is another similar widget that you may try IgnorePointer(). With IgnorePointer you set ignoring property as true or false, instead of absorbing.